# PrimeFaces: Get current column sort order in Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am currently trying to get the current order of columns in a PrimeFaces datatable whenever a user reorders them. Since the server-side event does not provide any parameters, I decided to use a JavaScript handler to do so.

```
function onColumnReorder(glossary) {
    var sortedColumnNames = ...
}
```

"glossary" is my datatable widget variable. Question is: how do I now retrieve the column names in their current order? Please note that I'm not talking about table data sorting, but just about the current order in which the columns appear in the table (left to right) - which may change of course, since "draggableColumns" is set to true.

Thanks for any advice and best regards
Pascal

Comment: Do you want to handle column reordering or sorting. Column reorder means replacing or repositioning columns in table, and sort is sort by values in some column (asc or desc). For sorting you have "sort" ajax event which has information which column is sorted.

Comment: I want to be able to store a user's column ordering (not value sorting) in his personal preferences.

Comment: You maybe can use `colReorder` ajax event on datatable and in backing bean find datatable component by id, and there you have `getColumns` method, which returns list of columns.

Comment: That would work as well - if not better. Though how can I retrieve the Datatable component? There's more than one of them in my page, generated by a <c:forEach>. I do know their respective ids, however.

Comment: You can bind the `<p:dataTable>` with your managed bean programmatically but that requires your managed bean have at least `@SessionScoped`.

Comment: @PascalKesseli You can use [UIViewRoot#findComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) to find component by id in you backing bean.

Comment: @partlov That eventually did the trick. So I scratched the JavaScript approach and used a server-side approachl using UIViewRoot#findComponent() and DataTable#getColumns().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First define `colReorder` AJAX event on `datatable`:

```
<p:ajax event="colReorder" listener="#{myBean.onColReorder}"/>
```

In `onColReorder` method find your datatable by id with [`UIViewRoot#findComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#findComponent%28java.lang.String%29) method. After you found your [`DataTable`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTable.html) object it is easy. Use [`getColumns()`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/component/datatable/DataTable.html#getColumns%28%29) method to get list of columns in `onColReorder()`:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
DataTable myDatatable = (DataTable) fc.getViewRoot().findComponent("your_datatable");
List<UIColumn> columns = myDatatable.getColumns();
```

Comment: why columns.get(1).getHeaderText() shows empty String even though i have 20 columns shown on datatable (i'm using p:columns)?

Comment: The question was about JavaScript and this is server side. Anyway, on PF5 it's as clean as `public void onColReorder(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) { DataTable myDatatable = (DataTable)event.getComponent(); ... }`

Answer (score 0):

```
var th =$(myTableWidgetVar.jqId).find('.ui-state-active');
```

returns you th with id `myTableId:myColumnId`, so you know which column has sorting enabled.

You can read now the triangle component:

th.find('.ui-sortable-column-icon');

And check which class it has defined:

- `'ui-icon-triangle-1-n'` for sorting ascending
- `'ui-icon-triangle-1-s'` for sorting descending

You'll have server callback on sort order change if you use `LazyDataModel`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I couldn't find more elegant solution that checking style classes. This information is not stored internally.